# send hover event programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just a quick question about hover events, How can I send a hover event to an element without the user hovering (programmatically).

example:

```
// Send hover event
$('#myDiv').sendHoverEvent();

// What to do once hovering
$('#myDiv').hover(console.log('hovering'));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#myDiv').trigger('mouseenter');
```

Comment: For others that are looking for an answer to this I used the above and it didn't work, I made a small change:  `$('#myDiv').trigger('mouseenter'); ` and it worked fine, might be a browser issue, not sure. Thanks again @Andrew Cooper

Comment: Same here, this should not be the chosen answer unless modified.

Answer (score 6):

Hover connects two events.  The one you want to trigger is mouseenter.

```
$('#myDiv').mouseenter();
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing Bootstrap tooltips showing it's better to use:

```
$('#myDiv').mouseenter();
```

`trigger('hover')` simply isn't sufficient to trigger it.