# How can I "trigger" css :hover selector?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image gallery on my page. There is an image and gallery navigation: *next* and *previous* buttons. By default the navigation is hidden, but when mouse cursor is over the right half of the image, *next* button is visible (**:hover** css selector). *next* button causes the animation, which involves navigation buttons. The problem is that right half of the image is not hovered after the end of the animation. I have to perform any mouse action to make *next* button visible.
So here is my qustion: is there any way to "trigger" **:hover** selector after the end of the animation?

*Note:* I suppose I can resolve this issue using jQuery `$(...).hover(in, out)` but I'm wondering if there is more fundamental solution that can affect **:hover**. After all, this selector is far more convenient for thit purpose.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: duplication ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074815/jquery-trigger-hover-on-anchor

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222724/send-hover-event-programmatically)?

Comment: I use Fancybox (v.2) jQuery plugin. It destroys navigation at the begining of the animation and creates it at the end.

Comment: Please note that `hover` pseudo-event is deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9 and up: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event

Comment: Well, no.. As far as I understand `trigger()` works only on JS events. But :hover selector uses some another mechanism (whih I haven't found yet) and can't be triggered with it.

Comment: No there is no way to trigger pseudo selectors using JS: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-triggering-css-pseudo-selectors-like-hover

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours of fiddling and [a little help from some friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458166/incredibly-strange-floating-behavior) I was able to come up with a better solution than before. The approach involves using a transparent element before the hovered element which expands from `width:0px; height:0px;` to `width:10000px; height:10000px;` and fires the same hover event as the gallery to display the `next` element. Using this approach, `next` is displayed no matter where the mouse is on the page, but only after the animation completes.

[**Updated Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qu82Z/12/)

```
body { overflow:hidden; }
#hoverHelper {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-1000px;
    margin-left:-1000px;
    animation: hhAnimation .001s 3s forwards;
}
#actualHover {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:teal;
    animation: yourAnimation 3s linear forwards;
}
#next {
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
    display: none;
}
#actualHover:hover ~ #next, #hoverHelper:hover ~ #next, #next:hover {
    display:inline-block;
}
@keyframes yourAnimation {
    0% { background:teal; }
    100% { background: red; }
}
@keyframes hhAnimation {
    0% { width:0px;
         height:0px;
}
100% { width:10000px;
       height:10000px;
     }
}
```

And the HTML (just make sure `#next` is after the others)

```
<div id='actualHover'></div>
<div id='hoverHelper'></div>
<a id='next'>Next</a>
```

I also added a little javascript to allow it to repeat and show you how it could be accessed

The solution *should* be fully cross-browser. The only negative thing about it is the `overflow:hidden` on the body which could be optimized further by either using javascript to determine the current window height/width and setting it to that (including on resize) or something similar

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I ran your demo, put cursor over the hidden "Next" and after the end of the animation "Next" didn't appear. I had to move mouse a little to see it.

Comment: You're correct, this will only fire in the case that the mouse moves again which in my opinion is acceptable if you don't want to use javascript like you know how to. Users move their mouse whenever they want to navigate anyway

Comment: But I liked the way you made your animation :) Is it cross-browser?

Comment: I'll add the other browser prefixes to make it so. One minute

Comment: You're right but in the case of the image gallery user may want to click "Next" several times and he doesn't expect navigation to be disappeared while he's doing it

Comment: Make it remain when it's hovered as well then, I just updated my demo

Comment: It looks like I'll refuse this _:hover_ stuff and make gallery navigation visible all the time. But the question of "triggering" _:hover_ is still open for me.

Comment: Thank's a lot anyway! I'll definitely try this pure-css animation sometime.

Comment: @Krivoi Is the updated solution any more satisfactory?