# Incredibly strange floating behavior

Tags: css, position, css-float, css-position

You're going to have to take a look at [**the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qu82Z/8/) for this one

The element I'm having trouble with, `hoverHelper`, is purposed to show `next` no matter what part of the body is hovered but only after the animation completes

When the animation ends, the floated (to take it out of the element flow) transparent overlay `hoverHelper` is given an absurdly high width and height to cover the entire page in order to apply a `hover` event to display the element `next`.

My problem, in essence, is that when the floated element is hovered, it registers the hover and acts as it should, but the other elements are negatively affected. For some reason the browser makes all following elements treat it like an un-floated element even though it never loses `float:left`. This means that the anchor and other succeeding elements are pushed thousands of pixels down, which is unacceptable

The easiest way to see this behavior is to inspect the element and force `:hover` on `actualHover`. Then you will see how it treats the floated `hoverHelper` like an un-floated element

Following is my HTML and relevant CSS

```
<div id='hoverHelper'></div>
<div id='actualHover'></div>
<a href="#" id='next'>Next</a>
<div class='other'></div>

body { overflow:hidden; max-width:200px; max-height:200px;}
#hoverHelper {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-1000px;
    margin-left:-1000px;
    animation: hhAnimation .001s 3s forwards;
}
#actualHover {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:teal;
    animation: yourAnimation 3s linear forwards;
}
#next {
    z-index:2;
    display: none;
}
#actualHover:hover ~ #next, #hoverHelper:hover ~ #next, #next:hover {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Also, I originally was using `position:absolute` on the overlay, but that prevented the `next` button from being clicked which is also unacceptable

I realize what I'm doing is unconventional, but to me this makes complete sense. Any insight as to what's going on?

**NOTE:**

This question was solved by way of an alternate solution, not of the problem being found. We still have no idea why the floated element has the behavior it does

Comment: Sorry I don't have a very useful answer, but is using Floats necessary when you can achieve (I believe) the same functionality using inline-block positioned elements inside a container of some sort? (Thereby letting you avoid funky float bugs, like in this case).

Comment: @HC_ I'm using float to (so I thought) move the element out of the element flow, nothing more. Similar to what `position:absolute` would do, but without some of the other effects `absolute` has

Comment: Okay so I think I am understanding this better, what is your desired effect for the other div?

Comment: What's the expected outcome..?

Comment: @JoshC I edited my question some, hopefully it's a little clearer

Comment: @JoshPowell The `other` div is simply to show that other elements besides `next` are affected, no other purpose

Comment: Alright, so I have been trying to figure this out.. What's the purpose of the 'hoverhelper', not quite understanding this, as it works perfectly fine without it.

Comment: The purpose of `hoverHelper` is to show `next` no matter what part of the body is hovered but only after the animation completes

Comment: You mention that you expect that `float` takes an element out of document flow. That is certainly not the case. A floated element will continue to affect the flow of other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to removing the element from the flow via floats, use `position:absolute`.

You said this was causing issues with `#next`, however if you add something like `position:relative` to it, it will be clickable. A `z-index` only has effect on positioned elements.

[**Working jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7T7TS/) - Added a semi-transparent background to the helperhover to demonstrate it.

Comment: But this is what I had before hand! This is what I started out doing, haha. The issue with this solution is that it places the absolute element in front of the others and prevents the `next` from being clicked

Comment: @Zeaklous Alright, didn't realize that... as for preventing `next` from being clicked, simply add `position:relative` to `#next` .. `z-index` only works on positioned elements. See the updated fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/7T7TS/

Comment: I swear I tried this several times before, haha. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Agreed, I have no idea why it would re-position the other elements